# Expect image with capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, capybara

I need to validate if the image exists but I'm not getting it, can someone help me?

I'm trying:

```rb
expect(page[:src]).to eq("https://www.viajanet.com.br/static/assets/platform/img/catalog/RIO/Rio-motor.jpg")
```

...but it doesn't work!

The path is: https://www.viajanet.com.br/static/assets/platform/img/catalog/RIO/Rio-motor.jpg

[image: code image]

Answer (score 0):

Why you would think you can call `page[:src]` to check anything? From your picture if I really needed to check this I would use something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('#banner-full', style: { 'background-image' => 'url("/static/assets/platform/img/catalog/RIO/Rio-motor.jpg")' })
```

Comment: Reason:
      expected to find visible css "#banner-full" with styles {"background-image"=>"url('static/assets/platform/img/catalog/RIO/Rio-motor.jpg')"} but there were no matches. Also found "Passagens Aéreas\nHotéis\nCarros\nEncontre os melhores valores e boa viagem!\nSó ida Ida e volta Vários destinos\nData de ida\nData de volta\nPesquisar\nNão defini as datas", which matched the selector but not all filters.
      ----------------------------------------------

Comment: Thank you but Unfortunately it didn't work!

Comment: Try with the leading / on the url -- I missed that -- updating the answer

Comment: @sabnola then query the elements style in your browser console and see what `background-image` is actually set to in the style, and check for that (it may be the full url, etc). But using the `style` filter will definitely work if given the correct information

Comment: The path is:https://www.viajanet.com.br/static/assets/platform/img/catalog/RIO/Rio-motor.jpg

Comment: The URL ís https://www.viajanet.com.br/ I need to expect image from Background..

Comment: @sabnola I've shown you the Capybara you need to use, you just need to inspect the element in the browser to see what the background-image style evaluates to and use that in the Capybara call

Comment: Also make sure your browser when testing is running wide enough, since that element disappears when the width gets small and it switches to a mobile layout

Comment: I've tried and I couldn't do it .. I'm new to this .. But as I said, let's never mind ... Thank you